# OS boot crashes after a few seconds on a new i9 CPU and a new motherboard

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard

Today I purchased a new CPU - i9 11900k on an LGA 1200 socket, and a new motherboard - "msi mag z590 tomahawk". I spent whole day assembling it all together and faced a lot of problems.

At first place I wasn't able to run my PC, I got the EzDebug CPU LED blinking red one time, without starting at all. Coolers did not spin. Somehow, after hours of suffering I noticed that one pin is slightly bent, so I fixed it using a thin screwdriver. My PC now starts and tries to boot an OS.

And now, my main issue is that after a few seconds of booting, it stucks. I have Win11 installed on one of my M2 SSDs, and if my PC starts booting to Win11, after a couple of seconds spinner freezes. Few times it gave me a BSOD with error `clock_watchdog_timeout`.
Then, I made an Ubuntu USB stick, when I try to boot from that stick, I have the same problem - after a few seconds everything freezes, but Ubuntu gave me an error info, I will attach it as an image.

How can I fix that? Or should I return the CPU or Motherboard to the seller and get another one? Is that a CPU fault, or a motherboard fault?

BIOS boots and works well. Also, I am attaching USB stick to a USB2 port, cause if it would be attached to a USB3 port, system stucks on a splash screen (which looks like a black screen with an underscore).
I tried:

- Booting from Windows at SSD
- Booting from Ubuntu at USB
- Booting from Windows Installer at USB (result is same as booting from SSD - spinner freezes after a couple of seconds)
- I tried to boot from memtest USB, but it simply does not boot and returns to the boot menu.
- Detaching RAM sticks and trying to boot with only one of the two RAM sticks I have. Also, tried different slots.
- Updating BIOS from usb stick, no changes.
- Disconnecting everything except for mouse and keyboard.
- Detaching GPU.

I cannot cross-test the CPU and the motherboard, cause I don't have any other LGA1200 boards or CPUs.

My hardware:
i9-11900k, 32GB RAM, MSI MAG Z590 Tomahawk motherboard, Nvidia RTX 3070TI, a couple of M.2 SSDs

Those RAM sticks I took from my old PC, they worked fine.

[Ubuntu error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTBs2.jpg)

P.S. Please, at least give me an advice, is that a CPU fault or a Motherboard fault, because I still can return it to the seller.

Comment: Is your motherboard firmware up to date?

Comment: @Mokubai I've updated BIOS via MSI's MFlash. If bios update == firmware update, then yes, I have the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a bad cpu. I took the CPU & MB to the seller's service center, they tried with an another i5 CPU, and everything was fine. I got my cpu replaced and now my PC works. Also, a hardware wizard guy replaced my bent pins.